# Deleting Room entry from RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, dao, delete-row, android-room

I am new to programming and I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTBiwKlO5IU) to create a `RecyclerView` making use of an adapter. I have no idea how to use the delete function from my Dao in relation to the `ImageButton.` I have next to each entry. Also, this is my first app, so please be gracious when you see things like ".allowMainThreadQueries".

**Activity with recyclerview:**

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ImageButton delete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "production").allowMainThreadQueries().build();

        final List<Student> students = db.studentDao().getAllUsers();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new StudentAdapter(students);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DatabaseActivity.this, DatabaseAddActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Student> students;

    public StudentAdapter(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.student_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StudentAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.first_name.setText(students.get(position).getFirstName());
        holder.last_name.setText(students.get(position).getLastName());
        holder.email.setText(students.get(position).getEmail());
    }

    //See how many items need to be displayed
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return students.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView first_name;
        public TextView last_name;
        public TextView email;
        public ImageButton delete;

        //What we are showing in the viewholder
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            first_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
            last_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface StudentDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM student ")
List<Student> getAllUsers();

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE monday = 1")
List<Student> getMonday();

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE tuesday = 1")
List<Student> getTuesday();

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE wednesday = 1")
List<Student> getWednesday();

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE thursday = 1")
List<Student> getThursday();

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE friday = 1")
List<Student> getFriday();

@Insert
void insertAll(Student... students);

@Delete
void delete(Student student);

@Update
void updateStudent(Student student);
}
```

Student Add:

```
public class DatabaseAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Calling needed resources
EditText firstName;
EditText lastName;
EditText email;
Button button;
CheckBox monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday;


//Defining which view.xml file to use
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database_add);

    //Using resources to find using .xml setup
    firstName = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    lastName = findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    monday = findViewById(R.id.monday_switch);
    tuesday = findViewById(R.id.tuesday_switch);
    wednesday = findViewById(R.id.wednesday_switch);
    thursday = findViewById(R.id.thursday_switch);
    friday = findViewById(R.id.friday_switch);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    //What happens when button is pressed
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "production").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
            Boolean mondayState = monday.isChecked();
            Boolean tuesdayState = tuesday.isChecked();
            Boolean wednesdayState = wednesday.isChecked();
            Boolean thursdayState = thursday.isChecked();
            Boolean fridayState = friday.isChecked();

            Student student = new Student(firstName.getText().toString(), lastName.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), mondayState, tuesdayState, wednesdayState, thursdayState, fridayState);
            db.studentDao().insertAll(student);
            startActivity(new Intent(DatabaseAddActivity.this,DatabaseActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Dao` code? And did you have a look at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Delete.html

Comment: There it is. I did look, but still no clue.

Answer (score 0):

In **DatabaseActivity:**

```
adapter = new StudentAdapter(db, students);
```

**UPDATED**

In your **Adapter** class:

```
AppDatabase db;
List<Student> students;

public StudentAdapter(AppDatabase db, List<Student> students) {
    this.db = db;
    this.students = students;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(StudentAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Student student = students.get(position);
    holder.first_name.setText(students.get(position).getFirstName());
    holder.last_name.setText(students.get(position).getLastName());
    holder.email.setText(students.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.delete.setOnClickListener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.delete(student);
                students.remove(student);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't delete so I checked log and it says "Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 11857215 , only wrote 11856960". I don't know if that's important but yeah. Also, new entries override old ones now

Comment: @Philedor Show your student adding code in activity?

Comment: Added it to the main comment

Comment: @Philedor I forgot add this stroke `students.remove(student);` in delete `onClick()` method after `db.delete(student);`